# How can I provide the Rest Framework API to intranet machine?

Tags: python, django, webserver

I use the rest framework write APIs, and when I runserver the website 
I can access the APIs in the development machine(the intranet ip is `10.10.10.111`):

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

But how can I access the API in other computer which is in the `10.10.10.0/24` intranet?

If can, this will become more convenient for our team to debugging.

Answer (score 1):

To make your development server view-able to other machines on the network, use its own IP address (e.g. 10.10.10.111) or 0.0.0.0.

[See the examples for running django projects on different ports and ip address.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/?from=olddocs#examples-of-using-different-ports-and-addresses)

The command will be:

```
django-admin runserver 0.0.0.0:<port>
```

or

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:<port>
```

You can then visit the site in `10.10.10.111:<port>` or `<your.machine.ip.address:port>` from same network.

Comment: I set to the `0.0.0.0:8001`, but I get the `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` Error in other computer.

Comment: if your your machine's ip is: `1.2.3.4` then type `1.2.3.4:8001` in the other computer.

Comment: can you ping your machine from the other machine?

Comment: Its normal, I can ping 10.10.10.111

Comment: Can you check running the devserver on port 80 ?

Comment: do you mean in the develop machine to runserver `0.0.0.0:80`?

Comment: Yes. run it on `0.0.0.0:80`

Comment: I can run devserver oin 80.

Answer (score 0):

What @salman said plus: This is most likely the host computers firewall blocking the packets. Depending on your OS try to selectively open this port.

**Edit**

Most likely the firewall on the **host** (*) machine will block the traffic. Also ask your admin if a firewall in the network blocks the port.

*) *host meaning „the machine running the server*

Comment: Do you mean the develop machine?

Answer (score 0):

Runserver in Django project:

```
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:<port>
```

stop the firewall in your develop OS, such as the CentOS7:

```
systemctl stop firewalld.service
```

then add the ALLOW_HOST in your project settings.py,
because your computer are connected use inner network, you can allow all:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```